# MySQL method for arbitrary grouping based on ranges of a value (histogram)

Tags: mysql

I have a simple dataset that has times for a script to complete various steps. The times are unpredictable but grouped mostly in a specific time range however I would like to graph this in groupings of 10ths of a second. (I know it's weird, it's a requirement of some report visualization stuff). I could just extend my case statement to be insanely long but I assume there is a better method to do this. What is that method?

```
SELECT
  COUNT(thing) AS value,
  CASE 
    WHEN (COALESCE(step1,0)+COALESCE(step2,0)+COALESCE(step3,0)+COALESCE(step4,0)+COALESCE(step5,0)+COALESCE(step6,0)+COALESCE(step7,0)) BETWEEN 0 AND 0.1 THEN '0-0.1'
    WHEN (COALESCE(step1,0)+COALESCE(step2,0)+COALESCE(step3,0)+COALESCE(step4,0)+COALESCE(step5,0)+COALESCE(step6,0)+COALESCE(step7,0)) BETWEEN 0.1 AND 0.2 THEN '0.1-0.2'
    WHEN (COALESCE(step1,0)+COALESCE(step2,0)+COALESCE(step3,0)+COALESCE(step4,0)+COALESCE(step5,0)+COALESCE(step6,0)+COALESCE(step7,0)) BETWEEN 0.2 AND 0.3 THEN '0.2-0.3'
    WHEN (COALESCE(step1,0)+COALESCE(step2,0)+COALESCE(step3,0)+COALESCE(step4,0)+COALESCE(step5,0)+COALESCE(step6,0)+COALESCE(step7,0)) BETWEEN 0.3 AND 0.4 THEN '0.3-0.4'
    WHEN (COALESCE(step1,0)+COALESCE(step2,0)+COALESCE(step3,0)+COALESCE(step4,0)+COALESCE(step5,0)+COALESCE(step6,0)+COALESCE(step7,0)) BETWEEN 0.4 AND 0.5 THEN '0.4-0.5'
    -- ad infinitum
  END AS metric
FROM table
GROUP BY metric
```

Comment: GROUP BY section executed before SELECT section so you cannot refer from group by to anything in select directly. You have to repeat these in group by section (SQL server usually smart enough to not calculate it twice) or convert the query in sub-query and do your grouping in outer query.

Comment: The query works as written...

Comment: Wow. Something new for me.

Comment: Yes, otherwise you could never GROUP BY a column which is an expression. Like `SELECT YEAR(create_date) AS yr ... GROUP BY yr`. You'd have to do that by making a derived-table subquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using ROUND and group by that column is good enough for me, if someone has a more interesting answer that allows things to be more arbitrary (like if it was an int and not a float or if buckets could be sized arbitrarily) I would love to see that and will mark it as an answer.

```
SELECT
  COUNT(thing) AS value,
  ROUND(COALESCE(step1,0)+COALESCE(step2,0)+COALESCE(step3,0)+COALESCE(step4,0)+COALESCE(step5,0)+COALESCE(step6,0)+COALESCE(step7,0),1) AS metric
FROM table
GROUP BY metric
```

Answer (score 1):

You could put your ranges in a temp table.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE metric_ranges (
    low  NUMERIC(4,1) NOT NULL,
    high NUMERIC(4,1) NOT NULL,
    metric VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (low, high),
    UNIQUE KEY (label)
);
INSERT INTO metric_ranges 
VALUES (0.0, 0.1, '0-0.1'),
       (0.1, 0.2, '0.1-0.2'),
       (0.2, 0.3, '0.2-0.3'),
       (0.3, 0.4, '0.3-0.4'),
       (0.4, 0.5, '0.4-0.5'),
       ...etc...
```

Then join your data to the ranges:

```
SELECT COUNT(t.thing) AS value, m.metric
FROM (
    SELECT thing, 
         COALESCE(step1,0) +
         COALESCE(step2,0) +
         COALESCE(step3,0) +
         COALESCE(step4,0) +
         COALESCE(step5,0) +
         COALESCE(step6,0) +
         COALESCE(step7,0) AS total
    FROM mytable
) AS t
JOIN metric_ranges AS m ON t.total >= m.low AND t.total < m.high
GROUP BY m.metric
```

It's up to you to make sure the ranges don't overlap!

Comment: Was hoping for something that could be changed on the fly arbitrarily. Might give this a try at some point. Thanks.

Comment: SQL query syntax must be fixed at the time you `prepare()` it. Expressions, columns, aliases, etc. cannot change as the query executes, so there's no way the query can change dynamically based on the data it scans.